Documentation of gtk xml builder definition
Where can I find the documentation of GTK xml definitions for gtk builder files?
For example for gtkwindow I found only this:
https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.Window.html#gtkwindow-as-gtkbuildable
Where are the docs of the other definitions like
<property name="title">GTK Window</property>
<property name="default-width">400</property>
<property name="default-height">300</property>
Any hint would be helpful.
I would expect a page where all xml details of all gtk widgets are.

https://de.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/GTK_mit_Builder
https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.Builder.html
https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.Widget.html#gtkwidget-as-gtkbuildable
Sorry the first is in german. Maybe it will help anyway.
Best regards.

The page you indicated already has everything you could want. The XML object structure is standardized. It starts with the object class:
<object class="GtkObject" id="optional_id">

like:
<object class="GtkToggleButton" id="_sections_button">

and properties use the pattern
<property name="something">value</property>

for example, if you wanted to change the Gtk.Window:decorated property, just use
<property name="decorated">False</property>

with property in the XML of your Gtk.Window. Another tag common to all containers is the <child> tag.
Generally, these XMLs are not created manually, in GTK4 we have Cambalache, which generates XML using drag and drop, and Workbench, which uses a simpler markup language (blueprint) to generate XML and contains an overwhelming amount of examples .
